# Certain continuous deformation of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a problem related to the geometry. Let $ABCD$ be a trapezoid on the $R^2$ with, let's say, sides $AB$ and $CD$ being parallel, and let continuous functions $f:R^2\rightarrow R$ and $g:R^2\rightarrow R$ be given. Is it possible to find a formula for the continuous function $F:R^2\rightarrow R$ such that $F(AB)=f(AB)$, $F(CD)=g(CD)$ and $F(AD),F(BC)$ still being line segments? The existence of such a continuous function $F$ is intuitively rather certain but I really don't know how to obtain a formula for it. I would be grateful for any reply or hint.

Comment: One approach is to keep line AC fixed, and then $F$ acts on B, D by scaling them out by a constant factor to the desired length, and another other point is scaled by the interpolation of distance from lines $AB, CD$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I can't see how it could help me in finding a formula for $F$. Because $f(AB)$ and $g(CD)$ geometrically give us curves in $R^3$, one can look at this problem as a problem of finding formula for continuous $F$ that graph contains these curves as well as line segments joining endpoints of these curves.